# How to print an entire Scroll View contents with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm really tired of searching for solutions and still none.
I have a UIScrollView with many elements inside and a button to print the calculations. When I click the button, Simulator offers me to print only one page (with the current screen contents). But what I need is a full controller printed.

Now the code is like:

```
@IBAction func printPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
        printInfo.jobName = "My Print Job"
        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.printingItem = self.view.toImage()
        printController.presentFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

And the extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```